# What input control is used to enter a Time Duration on Android?

Tags: android, time, duration

What input control is used to enter a Time Duration on Android?

No, it's not the Time Picker... that control is for a time-of-day, not a duration.

Further, in many domains Time Durations may be *negative*. This means that a full-featured input control must include the ability to enter duration negative values. (This is one reason why an EditText with a "time" inputType is not sufficient, as it does not guarantee the minus sign on the keypad.)

Comment: time duration in what format? can u plz provide one example

Comment: Ideally in hours, minutes, and seconds; and as mentioned including the ability to make it negative. Thanks!

Comment: hmm u can make ur custom control ..from edittext and apply rules on it

Comment: Sounds like you have very specific wants.  In this case, time to write your own control.

Comment: Hi Gabe, yes it's looking that way. I had thought accounting systems would have created a need for this type of control. Thanks for your input.